# Identify Poisson or Exponential Distribution and determine lambda

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I am trying to identify the distribution of my variable, $X$. It measures goals per minute of soccer players. Possible values are $[0,inf]$ and they are non integers. I believe this to be an exponential distribution because Poisson measures integers and we are dealing with the successive events over continual time not discrete.

If this is a Poisson distribution, what should I use as the data when plotting or comparing distributions? Every time I use the rate metric, I trigger an error for things like `poisson.test()` or `fitdist(x,"pois")` in R. When I use exponential distributions, everything works.

Also, is there a way to estimate $\lambda$ generally or do you do it for discrete time periods?

Comment: This looks like a probability density, which would not be in units of "goals per minute."

Comment: Well if the statistic measures the number of goals a player scored divided by the number of cumulative minutes they played, it is referred to as goals per minute. When analyzed on a per minute basis, we get a distribution. Do we not?

Comment: $f$ would then be in units of probability per (goals per minute).  It is, however, not a plausible candidate to describe that, in part because it assigns appreciable probability to cumulative playing times that are impossible (they extend beyond the length of any conceivable game).  For both those reasons something seems wrong about your description.

Comment: Generally to calculate goals per minute we sum a players goals and divide by their total minutes played in a season. So 10 goals/450 minutes = 0.022.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your variable is a count that you are expressing as a rate, the Poisson distribution would be a natural choice. If $Y$ represents the number of goals scored by player $i$, you could model $Y_i \sim \mbox{Poisson}(N_i\lambda)$, where $N_i$ is the total number of minutes that this player was on the field, and $\lambda$ is the rate parameter that can be interpreted as goals per minute.

You might find it useful to read about [Poisson processes](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-poisson-distribution-and-poisson-process-explained-4e2cb17d459). The example in that link of modeling meteors per minute might be similar to your question here.

Comment: Is the $\lambda$ parameter only defined at an interval? If I were to empirical test, I could use `poisson.test()` in R, with `x` being my data, but what would be my Time, `T`, value?

Comment: You can think of this $\lambda$ as representing the true goals per minute rate of the players. What kind of test are you trying to perform? Are you trying to carry out a hypothesis test of some kind, or is your goal to estimate the $\lambda$ parameter?

Comment: Both. Estimate  if I can and perform an empirical test. The trouble is whenever I test my rate stat or try to plot it, I run into errors because it is not a count stat. Hence why I still think it is exponentiall.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion due to the abstract statement of the question.  From your comments, Jack, it sounds like you have data about numbers of goals and playing time.  Depending on your objective, you might want to be thinking about a Poisson regression model.  Asking about some kind of probability density for goals per minute may be a less than fruitful direction to take.

Comment: You are correct that only a count can arise from a Poisson distribution. As @whuber mentioned too, a Poisson regression might be the right direction. Your variable -- number of goals -- is a count. The true rate would be represented by $\lambda$. If $Y$ is the number of goals and $N$ is the number of minutes, then $Y \sim \mbox{Poisson}(N\lambda)$ is the natural way to model your data. Note that $Y$ is not the rate itself; the number of minutes is being accounted for through $N$. In Poisson regression, we would think of the minutes $N$ as the offset.

Comment: Here is a simple example in R:

```
goals <- c(3,4,5,2,1,3)
minutes <- c(10,20,30,5,5,15)
glm(goals~.,data=data.frame(goals=goals),family=poisson,offset=log(minutes))
```

If you exponentiate the intercept term from the resulting fit, that represents your estimate $\lambda$ of the true rate of goals per minute. Then for any individual player, their number of goals could be modeled as arising from a Poisson distribution with parameter $N \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is this estimated value and $N$ is the minutes they play.

Comment: With that information, I was able to estimate a $\lambda$ by exponentiating the intercept as suggested, it is very small less than 0.01. But when the question is what does the distribution of goals per minute look like, am I graphing a poisson distribution with this lambda calculated? My first idea was a histogram of goals per minute, but that would not be a Poisson process. If I try a standard ggplot method with ```ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0:10)), aes(x)) +
    geom_point(aes(y=dpois(x, lambda)), colour="red")```, since my lambda is so small the 0th point is at 1 and everything else at 0.

Comment: Your approach to plotting should work. It's just that your current plot will not look very meaningful since the rate of goals per minute $\lambda$ is so small that it's very unlikely to have more than 0 goals per minute. You could make your plot easier to interpret by picking some amount of time, such as 100 minutes or whatever makes sense in your context, and recreating the same plot but with `dpois(x,100*lambda)`. Then this will show you the distribution of number of goals per 100 minutes.